# Jquery Query builder Grid search using datatable in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, datatables, zend-framework3, jquery-query-builder

Using PHP I want to add custom search like http://querybuilder.js.org/demo.html into existing grid/listing.Current grid display using datatable using ajax.

Listing have five fields : Name,Email,Phone,Gender,Zipcode

Now customize search on above five fields like or same as http://querybuilder.js.org/demo.html.

Any one have suggestion then Please help me.

Comment: Actually currently I had developed listing page using datatable ajax.Now I want custom search same or like  http://querybuilder.js.org/demo.html in my current implemented listing page. In my application there are 10-15 listing page which were implement using datatable ajax.So I can't redevelop it,So I just want to add custom search in my current listing page like  http://querybuilder.js.org/demo.html. Please help me.